# ASP.NET Core ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement for multiple scopes not working as intended?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I came across something and would like to ask you for your advice if this is intended behavior or a major security risk.

What I intended to do is authorizing two API controller actions with different polices. One policy requires one scope, the other policy requires two scopes.

Therefor I defined the scopes

- scope:1
- scope:2

The controller I intend to authorize and how I do it looks like:

```
  [ApiController]
  [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
  //intentionally no authorize here
  public class TestContoller : ControllerBase 
  {

    [HttpGet("single")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = nameof(SingleScopePolicy))]
    public IActionResult GetSingle() { return Ok("success"); }

    [HttpGet("double")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = nameof(DoubleScopePolicy))]
    public IActionResult GetDouble() { return Ok("success"); }

  }
```

The intended behavior (as I understand it right now) is that it returns forbidden when SingleScopePolicy detects it does not have scope:1 and DoubleScopePolicy detects it does not have scope:1 **AND** scope:2. The AND is the relevant part!

In the Startup.cs I configured the authorization and added the scopes as like (intentionally no default policy for testing)

```
public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection service) 
  {
    // ...

    services.AddAuthorization
    (
      options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy(nameof(SingleScopePolicy), new SingleScopePolicy());
        options.AddPolicy(nameof(DoubleScopePolicy), new DoubleScopePolicy());
      }
    );

    // ...
  }
```

And I defined my two policies via code:

```
  public class SingleScopePolicy : AuthorizationPolicy
  {
    public SingleScopePolicy() : base 
    (
      new IAuthorizationRequirement[]
      {
        new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("scope", new string[] { "scope:1 })
      },
      new string[] { "Bearer" }
    ) { }
  }

  public class DoubleScopePolicy : AuthorizationPolicy
  {
    public DoubleScopePolicy() : base 
    (
      new IAuthorizationRequirement[]
      {

        // does not work (never returns forbid)
        //new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("scope", new string[] { "scope:1", "scope:2" }) 

        // works
        new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("scope", new string[] { "scope:1" }),
        new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("scope", new string[] { "scope:2" }),
      },
      new string[] { "Bearer" }
    ) { }
  }
```

---

My question is now should claims authorization requirement in the DoubleScopePolicy work or is it intended that this does not work.

Using the line below actually NEVER returns forbidden and always allows access. This kind of makes me wow because it offers you a string[] which I would understand as "hey, give me two and I will check there are both". If I define it seperatly in two lines it works as intended (by me).

```
new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("scope", new string[] { "scope:1", "scope:2" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement.cs#L62) for `ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement` shows that the `AllowedValues` property is treated as an *or* operation:

```
found = context.User.Claims.Any(
    c => string.Equals(c.Type, requirement.ClaimType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
          && requirement.AllowedValues.Contains(c.Value, StringComparer.Ordinal));

// ...

if (found)
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
```

As you've already described, you can add multiple `ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement`s in order to treat the check as an *and* operation.